# Alternatives for $() / jquery()

Tags: jquery

I would like to use my own symbol instead of *$()* or *jquery()*. Is it possible? I strongly feel **NO**.

Comment: One simple way is to assign your symbol (it must be a valid name for variable) with jQuery. e.g. `_ = $;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course it's possible. You can just assign the `jQuery` object (or the `$` object - they reference the same thing)  to a new identifier:

```
var myNewName = jQuery;
```

You can then use that just as you would currently use `jQuery` or `$`:

```
var elems = myNewName(".someClass");
```

Note that this will *not* relinquish jQuery's control of the `$` variable. To do that (e.g. if you're using another library such as PrototypeJS that uses the `$` identifier itself), you can use the the `jQuery.noConflict()` method as shown in other answers.

Comment: Oh! It's so simple. Probably that is why a down vote :( Anyways, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
// Do something with jQuery
j("div p").hide();
```

As seen [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Answer (score 1):

Beyond just assigning $ or jQuery to a new variable name, you can also use noConflict to remove the global references to $ and jQuery. Using the return of noConflict, you can create an entirely new reference.

```
// remove reference to $ and jQuery
var mySymbol = jQuery.noConflict(true);

// remove reference to $ only
var mySymbol = jQuery.noConflict()
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/